# DIscord.py commands.command slower than on_message

Tags: discord.py

Good morning,
Using my discord bot I found that commands with prefix react slower than on_message event. Let me explain better: if I want that the bot returns me "hello", if I use a command '!hello' it takes longer than a listener with the same code, that returns me 'hello' if I write a text released from the prefix. When I run a command, in the bot console I see that the program not immediatly process the command, but it takes sometimes about ten seconds.

This is the message listener cog

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Message(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        #await self.client.process_commands(message)
        channel = message.channel
        username = str(message.author)
        userMessage = str(message.content)

        print(f'{message.guild} - {username}: {userMessage} ({channel})')
        
        if message.author == self.client.user:
            return

        await sendMessage(channel, username, userMessage)

async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(Message(client))


async def sendMessage(channel, username, userMessage):
    try:
        risposta = Risposte(username, userMessage)
        await channel.send(risposta)
    except Exception as eccezione:
        print(eccezione)

def Risposte(username, userMessage) -> str:
    username=username.split('#')[0]
    userMessage = userMessage.lower()

    if userMessage == 'hello':
        return 'hello'
```

This is the command:

```
@commands.command()
    async def hello(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("hello")
```

I would to know if it is a connection problem (I'm hosting it), or an other issue.

Thanks for your attention.